# Joomla 4: get all users in a usergroup

Tags: joomla-4.x, user-groups

I need an array of all usernames from a certain usergroup.
How can I update my Joomla 3 component code for use in Joomla 4?

```
jimport( 'joomla.access.access' );
$customers = JAccess::getUsersByGroup(2);
jimport( 'joomla.user.user' );
foreach($customers as $customer){
    $user = JFactory::getUser($customer);
    $userID = $user->id;
    $arr = array();
    $arr[$userID] = $user->username;
}
$this->users = $arr;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jimport` statements are replaced by adding `use` statements prior to your `class` statement. The `getUsersByGroup()` is still valid and has no reference to being depreciated while the `JFactory::getUser()`/`Factory::getUser()` will work with Joomla 4 but is depreciated in Joomla 5.

```
use Joomla\CMS\Access\Access;
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

...

$userfactory = Factory::getContainer()->get(UserFactoryInterface::class);

$customers = Access::getUsersByGroup(2);

foreach($customers as $customer)
{
    $user = $userfactory->loadUserById($customer);
     $userID = $user->id;
     $arr = array();
     $arr[$userID] = $user->username;
}

$this->users = $arr;
```

Comment: Do you mean to clear the array on each iteration with `$arr = array();`?   ...we must not trust the code in questions ;)  Maybe `$this->users[$user->id] = $user->username;`

Comment: @Irata The code provided gives an error `Exception Type: Joomla\DI\Exception\KeyNotFoundException` with a message `UserFactoryInterface has not been registered with the container` in the stack trace. I had to add the code `use Joomla\CMS\User\UserFactoryInterface;` to get it to work.

Comment: @mickmackusa I have added your suggestion to my code.

Answer (score 0):

You could pull this straight from the db with something like the following

```
$group_id = 2;

$db = \Joomla\CMS\Factory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('b.username')
    ->from($db->qn('#__user_usergroup_map', 'a'))
    ->join('INNER', $db->qn('#__users', 'b') . ' ON ' . $db->qn('a.user_id') . ' = ' . $db->qn('b.id'))
    ->where($db->qn('a.group_id') . ' = ' . $db->q($group_id));
$db->setQuery($query);
$usernames = $db->loadColumn();

// this should show the contents of the array
echo '<pre>' . print_r($usernames,1) . '</pre>';
```